# Как поменять вид XML данных?

Tags: python, xml

Мне нужно импортировать XML файл с набором данных товаров, одна строка(товар) в данном файле выглядит так:

```
<root>
  <Big_Images>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg1.com</item>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg2.com</item>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg3.com</item>
  </Big_Images>
  <Title>
    <item>Название</item>
  </Title>
  <Price>
    <item>9.99</item>
  </Price>
  <Main_Info>
    <item>
      &lt;div class="goodInfo"&gt; Куча html кода и текста &lt;/div&gt;
    </item>
  </Main_Info>
</root>
```

Проверял данный xml и он валиден, однако компонент ни в какую не хочет обрабатывать такую() формулировку.

В итоге надо убрать item и на их месте поставить имена "родителей" что бы было

```
<root>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg1.com</Big_Images>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg2.com</Big_Images>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg3.com</Big_Images>
  <Title>Название</Title>
  <Price>9.99</Price>
  <Main_Info>
    &lt;div class="goodInfo"&gt; Куча html кода и текста &lt;/div&gt
  </Main_Info>
</root>
```

Возможно ли это реализовать и если да то как?

P.S. Предпочтительно реализовать на Python так как в остальных я мало осведомлен

Comment: Алгоритм такой. Грузишь XML в Python. В цикле получаешь содержимое item'ов, вставляешь в созданный "правильный" блок. Повторяешь для следующей записи. Пробуй писать, будут ошибки, выкладывай пример кода, поможем.

Comment: Можно с помощью XSLT. И даже без питона. В некоторых ОС бывают готовые утилиты для трансформации XML через XSLT (msxsl.exe для windows например) Наверняка и для питона найдётся подобный трансформатор. Правда придется освоить XSLT, но это совсем не сложно и возможно некоторые аспекты этой техники пригодятся ещё где либо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('С:/полный/путь/к/файлу/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent = root.iterfind('.//item')
for element in parent:
    element.tag = root.find('.//item/..').tag
tree.write('С:/полный/путь/к/файлу/out.xml')
```

Имена родителей удалить(сохранив их дочерние элементы) увы не получилось и скорость при больших файлах не самая лучшая.

Comment: Если есть рекомендации то буду рад если напишете их в комментариях =)

Answer (score 0):

```
#подключаем библиотеку
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
dom = minidom.parse(filename)
dom.normalize()

# Читаем Big_Images
pars = dom.getElementsByTagName("Big_Images")[0]

# Читаем элементы Big_Images
for par in pars:
     item = par.getElementsByTagName("item")[0]
```